# SSE code to set float variable to 0.0f or 1.0f based on comparison

Tags: c, performance, optimization, sse, simd

I have two arrays: `char* c` and `float* f` and I need to do this operation:

```
// Compute float mask
float* f;
char* c;
char c_thresh;
int n;

for ( int i = 0; i < n; ++i )
{
    if ( c[i] < c_thresh ) f[i] = 0.0f;
    else                   f[i] = 1.0f;
}
```

I am looking for a fast way to do it: without conditionals and using SSE (4.2 or AVX) if possible.

If using `float` instead of `char` can result in faster code, I can change my code to use floats only:

```
// Compute float mask
float* f;
float* c;
float c_thresh;
int n;

for ( int i = 0; i < n; ++i )
{
    if ( c[i] < c_thresh ) f[i] = 0.0f;
    else                   f[i] = 1.0f;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: How many lanes are you planning to use in the char vectors? Four..?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pretty easy, just do the comparison, convert bytes to dword, AND with 1.0f: (not tested, and this isn't meant to be copy&paste code anyway, it's meant to show how you do it)

```
movd xmm0, [c]          ; read 4 bytes from c
pcmpgtb xmm0, threshold ; compare (note: comparison is >, not >=, so adjust threshold)
pmovzxbd xmm0, xmm0     ; convert bytes to dwords
pand xmm0, one          ; AND all four elements with 1.0f
movdqa [f], xmm0        ; save result
```

Should be pretty easy to convert to intrinsics.

Comment: `movps` can be used instead of `movd` and `movdqa`

Answer (score 5):

The following code uses SSE2 (i think).

It performs 16 comparisons of bytes in one instruction (`_mm_cmpgt_epi8`). It assumes that `char` is signed; if your `char` is unsigned, it requires additional fiddling (flipping the most significant bit of each `char`).

The only non-standard thing it does is using the magic number `3f80` to represent the floating-point constant `1.0`. The magic number is actually `0x3f800000`, but the fact that the 16 LSB are zero makes it possible to do the bit fiddling more efficiently (using 16-bit masks instead of 32-bit ones).

```
// load (assuming the pointer is aligned)
__m128i input = *(const __m128i*)c;
// compare
__m128i cmp = _mm_cmpgt_epi8(input, _mm_set1_epi8(c_thresh - 1));
// convert to 16-bit
__m128i c0 = _mm_unpacklo_epi8(cmp, cmp);
__m128i c1 = _mm_unpackhi_epi8(cmp, cmp);
// convert ffff to 3f80
c0 = _mm_and_si128(c0, _mm_set1_epi16(0x3f80));
c1 = _mm_and_si128(c1, _mm_set1_epi16(0x3f80));
// convert to 32-bit and write (assuming the pointer is aligned)
__m128i* result = (__m128i*)f;
result[0] = _mm_unpacklo_epi16(_mm_setzero_si128(), c0);
result[1] = _mm_unpackhi_epi16(_mm_setzero_si128(), c0);
result[2] = _mm_unpacklo_epi16(_mm_setzero_si128(), c1);
result[3] = _mm_unpackhi_epi16(_mm_setzero_si128(), c1);
```

Comment: That's a clever answer.  But why use implicit loads/stores?  You're already using explicit SSE intrinscs why not finish the job with explicit loads/stores and make the code less compiler dependent?

Comment: BTW, I think this code could be converted to AVX2 simply by changing `_mm_` to _mm256` and `si128` to `si256` and get the same result but maybe faster than the SSE solution.

Comment: I just tried your implicit load with MSVC2013 and it worked!  I did not expect that.  I though these implicit loads/stores would only work in GCC.

Answer (score 4):

By switching to floats you can auto-vectorize the loop in GCC and not worry about intrinsics.  The following code will do what you want and auto-vectorizes.

```
void foo(float *f, float*c, float c_thresh, const int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        f[i] = (float)(c[i] >= c_thresh);
    }
}
```

Compiled with

```
g++  -O3 -Wall  -pedantic -march=native main.cpp -ftree-vectorizer-verbose=1
```

You can see the results and edit/compile the code yourself at [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/693d0271446eee3f).  However, MSVC2013 did not vectorize the loop.

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
f[i] = (c[i] >= c_thresh);
```

At least this removes the conditional.

Comment: I used this and change `c` and `c_thresh` to floats and it auto-vectorized in GCC.

Answer (score 2):

AVX version:

```
void floatSelect(float* f, const char* c, size_t n, char c_thresh) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        if (c[i] < c_thresh) f[i] = 0.0f;
        else f[i] = 1.0f;
    }
}

void vecFloatSelect(float* f, const char* c, size_t n, char c_thresh) {
    const auto thresh = _mm_set1_epi8(c_thresh);
    const auto zeros = _mm256_setzero_ps();
    const auto ones = _mm256_set1_ps(1.0f);
    const auto shuffle0 = _mm_set_epi8(3, -1, -1, -1, 2, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1, -1);
    const auto shuffle1 = _mm_set_epi8(7, -1, -1, -1, 6, -1, -1, -1, 5, -1, -1, -1, 4, -1, -1, -1);
    const auto shuffle2 = _mm_set_epi8(11, -1, -1, -1, 10, -1, -1, -1, 9, -1, -1, -1, 8, -1, -1, -1);
    const auto shuffle3 = _mm_set_epi8(15, -1, -1, -1, 14, -1, -1, -1, 13, -1, -1, -1, 12, -1, -1, -1);

    const size_t nVec = (n / 16) * 16;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < nVec; i += 16) {
        const auto chars = _mm_loadu_si128(reinterpret_cast<const __m128i*>(c + i));
        const auto mask = _mm_cmplt_epi8(chars, thresh);
        const auto floatMask0 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(mask, shuffle0);
        const auto floatMask1 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(mask, shuffle1);
        const auto floatMask2 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(mask, shuffle2);
        const auto floatMask3 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(mask, shuffle3);
        const auto floatMask01 = _mm256_set_m128i(floatMask1, floatMask0);
        const auto floatMask23 = _mm256_set_m128i(floatMask3, floatMask2);
        const auto floats0 = _mm256_blendv_ps(ones, zeros, _mm256_castsi256_ps(floatMask01));
        const auto floats1 = _mm256_blendv_ps(ones, zeros, _mm256_castsi256_ps(floatMask23));
        _mm256_storeu_ps(f + i, floats0);
        _mm256_storeu_ps(f + i + 8, floats1);
    }
    floatSelect(f + nVec, c + nVec, n % 16, c_thresh);
}
```

Comment: `auto` and `reinterpret_cast` are C++ features; maybe replace them by `__m128i` (or a variant thereof) and C type-cast syntax.

Comment: I didn't notice the question specified C, conversion to C left as an exercise for the reader...

Comment: AVX is not going to be very good for this compared to SSE.  AVX2 would be good solution though.

Comment: Agreed, AVX doesn't buy you much here. I don't have access to a Haswell CPU to test though.

Answer (score 1):

Converting to

```
f[i] = (float)(c[i] >= c_thresh);
```

- will also auto-vectorizable with Intel Compiler (mentioned by others to be true for gcc as well)

In case you need to auto-vectorize some **branchy loop in general**, - you could also try **#pragma ivdep** or **pragma simd** (the last one is a part of [Intel Cilk Plus](http://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-cilk-plus) and OpenMP 4.0 standards). These pragmas **auto-vectorize** given code in portable way for SSE, AVX and future vector extensions (like [AVX512](http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2013/avx-512-instructions)). These pragmas are supported by Intel Compiler (all known versions), Cray and PGI  compilers (ivdep only), *probably* upcoming GCC4.9 release and partially supported by MSVC (ivdep only) starting from VS2012.

For given example I didn't change anything (kept if and char*), just added pragma ivdep:

```
void foo(float *f, char*c, char c_thresh, const int n) {
    #pragma ivdep
    for ( int i = 0; i < n; ++i )
    {
        if ( c[i] < c_thresh ) f[i] = 0.0f;
        else                   f[i] = 1.0f;
    }
}
```

On my Core i5 with no AVX support (SSE3 only), for n = 32K (32000000), having c[i] generated randomly and using c_thresh equal to 0 (we use signed char), given code provides about ~5x speed-up due to vectorization with ICL.

Full test (with additional test case correctness check) is available [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/47e02b134b5b1150) (it's coliru, i.e. gcc4.8 only, no ICL/Cray; that's why it doesn't vectorize in coliru env).

It should be possible to do further performance optimization by dealing with more pre-fetching, alignment and type conversions pragmas/optimizations. Also adding restrict keyword (or **restrict** depending on compiler used) may be used instead of ivdep/simd for given simple case, while for more general cases - pragmas simd/ivdep are most powerful.

Note: in fact #pragma ivdep "instructs the compiler to ignore assumed cross-iterational dependencies" ( *roughly* speaking those who leads to data races if you parallelize the same loop). Compilers are very conservative in these assumptions by well-known reasons. In given case there is obviously no write-after-read or read-after-write dependencies. If needed, one could validate presence of such dependencies at least on given workload with dynamic tools like [Advisor XE](http://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-advisor-xe) Correctness analysis, like btw shown in my comments below.

Comment: What version of GCC does this work on?  Mine does not recognize `ivdep` (on [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/)).  However, MSVC does recognize it but it still does not vectorize.  Anyway, did you check that you get the right results?  `ivdep` is making the compiler do something it does not know if it should do.

Comment: @redrum, I just double-checked: in fact both #pragma ivdep and #pragma simd (with Cilk Plus) are expected to be supported starting from gcc4.9 only (this fall?). MSVC supports #pragma ivdep starting from MSVS2012; but separate question is how efficient their "young" vectorizer is (in my env it also doesn't vectorize given loop). Originally I mixed up GCC with Cray or PGI compilers (those who actually support pragma idvdep and pragma vector for some time, as well as Intel Compiler). Thanks for validation, I will update my post.

Comment: @redrum; WRT your second question. #pragma ivdep "instructs the compiler to ignore assumed cross-iterational dependencies" (i.e. _roughly_ speaking those who leads to data races if you parallelize the same loop). Every compiler is very conservative in these assumptions as explained for example [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nativeconcurrency/archive/2012/05/22/auto-vectorizer-in-visual-studio-11-did-it-work.aspx).  In given case there is obviously no write-after-read or read-after-write dependencies. But in general if needed, one could validate presence of such dependencies with dynamic tools.

Comment: I would be happy to upvote you if you verify that you actually get the correct result.  Since I don't have access to a compiler which I can test this I can't verify it myself.

Comment: OK, I verified it. Here is mine full test: [coliru code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/47e02b134b5b1150). Of course coliru' g++ doesn't vectorize in second case. On my SSE-only system, with ICL14, I got following output:c:\users\testVect2\Release\testVect2.exe

No-vector calculations took 313ms , counter = 32000855
Vector calculations took 68ms ,     counter = 32000855

Comment: I also run automated Advisor XE Correctness check on "annotated version" of test. The following output confirms it's clean from cross-iterational dependencies: [ "MyRoot\Advisor XE 2013\bin32\advixe-cl" -collect correctness -mrte-mode=auto -project-dir "c:\Users\testVect2\My Advisor XE Results - testVect2" -- "c:\users\testVect2\Release\testVect2Annotated.exe"
"MyRoot\Advisor XE 2013\bin32\advixe-cl" -report correctness -project-dir "c:\Users\testVect2\My Advisor XE Results - testVect2" --report-output 1.txt
more 1.txt
Problems:
Remark MySite1 Not a problem] - i.e. no real problem reported.